# How to find $\int_0^1 \int_x^1 \arctan(\frac{y}{x})dxdy$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find $$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)~dxdy$$ I am not looking for any full solutions just some small hints to get me started would be great.

Comment: Have you tried inverting the order of the integrals?

Comment: No I am unfamiliar with how to do that.

Comment: should it be $dydx$ rather than $dxdy$?

Comment: No it is stated as $dxdy$ that is why I am confused because then to change it is saying $x=x$ and $1=x$

Comment: What kind of calculus course (or text) will even pose such a problem without teaching about different orders of integration first? That surprises me.

Comment: Hint: Try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

Comment: No course Harald I am learning myself.

Comment: Just realised this is a duplicate sorry. Please close the question thank you.

Comment: could you please provide the like to the duplicate stuff? Thanks!

Comment: Suppose he is referring to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256465/find-int-limits-01-int-limits-x1-arctan-bigg-frac-yx-bigg-d?rq=1 from the Related section

Answer (score 0):

**HINT  EDITED**

There are two possible interpretations of the double integral in question over the region below

[image]

$$ \int_0^1 \left[\int_x^1 \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)~dy\ \right] dx.$$

or

$$\int_0^1 \left[\color{red}{\int_0^y}  \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\color{red}{dx}\right] dy$$

(That is, first you have to integrate with respect to $y$ since you cannot integrate with respect to $x$ if the limits depend on $x$. Or, if you want to integrate first by $x$ then the limits are $0$ and $y$.)

I've suggested the first interpretation because I knew the antiderivative of $\arctan.$

[Then use the well known facts that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

1. $$\int \arctan (u)\ du =u\arctan(u)-\frac12\ln(u^2+1)+C$$
2. If $g$ is an antiderivative of $f$  then $\frac1Ag$ is an antiderivative of $f(Au)$.

Comment: OP seems to mean $dxdy$ ...

Comment: @Math-fun: The OP unconsciously mean $dS$ denoted by $dxdy$. However, I cannot be certain about that.

Comment: I asked OP for clarification, see the comments ...

Comment: @Math-fun: Yes, I see your question and then his answer. Yet, I claim that $"dxdy"$ is meaningless. This should be explained somewhat better...

Comment: @Math-fun: I edited my answer. I think I've found out what went wrong in the OP. It is possible to integrate first by  $x$ but then the limits of integration are different.

Comment: It could well be that OP wanted to have the inner integral over $y\to1$ ...